# How to configure mechanism in thrift_sasl

Tags: python, windows, hive, sasl

I'm trying to connect to Hive with a Windows client using Python and am getting this error:

`(pyhive-test) C:\dev\sandbox\pyhive-test>python test.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 4, in <module> conn = hive.Connection(host='localhost', port='10000', database='default', auth='NONE') File "C:\Users\harnerd\Anaconda3\envs\pyhive-test\lib\site-packages\pyhive\hive.py", line 192, in __init__ self._transport.open() File "C:\Users\harnerd\Anaconda3\envs\pyhive-test\lib\site-packages\thrift_sasl\__init__.py", line 84, in open raise TTransportException(type=TTransportException.NOT_OPEN, thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'`

How do I configure mechanisms for thrift_sasl? There is no documentation that I've been able to find.

FWIW, the line causing the error is in `thrift_sasl/__init__.py`:

`ret, chosen_mech, initial_response = self.sasl.start(self.mechanism)`

`self.mechanism` is 'PLAIN'; `chosen_mech` and `initial_response` are empty strings (''). ret is False, which causes the exception to be thrown.